# How to connect JBL Live 400Bt bluetooth microphone

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone

The JBL Live 400bt headphones are connected via Bluetooth to my computer.

[image: Audio volume advanced]

I can select the JBL to play audio but it does not appear as a Microphone

[image: Audio volume applications]

I also checked pavucontrol but is displayed just as monitor.

[image]

I'm using Kubuntu

Linux gmork 4.15.0-96-generic #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 1 03:25:46 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

I have tested the headphones with my mobile phone and audio and microphone work properly.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1):

- JBL Live Pro+ TWS BT profiles supported A2DP V1.3, AVRCP V1.6, HFP V1.7. BT version 5.0
- JBL Live 400Bt BT profiles supported A2DP V1.3, AVRCP V1.5, HFP V1.6. BT version 4.2
- JBL Free profiles supported A2DP 1.3, AVRCP 1.6, HFP 1.7. BT 4.2

> A2DP: Source role - the device that sends audio. Sink role - the device that receives audio.
>
> HSP: Audio Gateway role - the device that the headset is connected to. The HSP profile is typically used in phone calls, and this is the device that is connected to the cellular network (for cellular phone calls) or to the internet (for VoIP calls). Typically a cellular phone or a PC.
> Headset role - the headset, obviously. This is where the speakers and microphone are.
>
> HFP: Audio Gateway role - the device that the hands-free device is connected to. The HFP profile is typically used for cellular phone calls, and this is the device that is connected to the cellular network. Typically a cellular phone. Hands-Free Unit role - the device with the speakers and microphone.

When you use A2DP it is a headphone, not a headset. That would require HSP/HFP.

1. So possibly A2DP is used as it matches the problem. Switch A2DP sink to HSP/HFP:

   ```
    /etc/pulse/default.pa
    load-module module-bluetooth-policy
   ```

   append

   ```
    auto_switch=2
   ```

   Remark: this is a permanent switch. The catch is that HSP/HFP limits to 8000Hz frequency range. That is fine for voice but is not for listening to music.
2. If that works you can make profiles so you can toggle between the 2 on commandline. Use

   ```
    pactl list cards | grep Name
   ```

   to get the ID for the BT card and you can toggle with ...

   ```
    pactl set-card-profile {id} a2dp_sink
    pactl set-card-profile {id} headset_head_unit
   ```
3. You could also switch to `pipewire` as it supports HSP, HFP and A2DP by itself; you can select it from the GUI. Replacing pulseaudio by pipewire: https://askubuntu.com/a/1333405/15811

---

4. something to check 1st :)

   ```
   /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf
   ```

   check headset is not disabled:

   ```
   [General]
   Disable=Headset
   ```

---

After changing to restart pulseaudio and BT use...

```
pulseaudio -k
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

---

If neither works please leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

Execute these commands on the terminal one by one.

```
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
sudo apt update
sudo apt install blueman
bluetoothctl
show
pair EC:82:12:6F:30:96
```

note: `pair [headphone mac address]`