# How to replace pulseaudio with pipewire on Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, pipewire

As Ubuntu 21.04 includes pipewire for video streams and screen sharing by default, I am wondering whether or not it is possible to replace pulseaudio completely with pipewire.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes indeed, this is possible and fairly simple, just follow the steps described in the [Debian docs:](https://wiki.debian.org/PipeWire)

First install the pipewire-audio-client-libraries package.

```
sudo apt install pipewire-audio-client-libraries
```

Create this empty file:

```
touch /etc/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
```

Create a pipewire-pulse service by copying the example files:

```
cp /usr/share/doc/pipewire/examples/systemd/user/pipewire-pulse.* /etc/systemd/user/
```

Run these three commands as your regular user (not as root):

```
// Check for new service files with:
systemctl --user daemon-reload
// Disable and stop the PulseAudio service with:
systemctl --user --now disable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
// Enable and start the new pipewire-pulse service with:
systemctl --user --now enable pipewire pipewire-pulse
```

You can check which server is in use by, as your regular user, running:

```
pactl info | grep '^Server Name'
```

If it's using PipeWire, the server name will be "PulseAudio (On PipeWire 0.3.19)"

To makeit work I had to "mask" the PulseAudio service by running:

```
systemctl --user mask pulseaudio
```

And then restarting the PipeWire services:

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire pipewire-pulse
```

This will block the PulseAudio service from being activated outright. If you wish to restore previous functionality, you'll need to run the same command again with the "unmask" action.

Comment: Arch has a package which does essentially this. It's surprising Debian haven't done it a in a similar fashion.

Comment: Do not forget to install libspa-0.2-bluetooth or your bluetooth devices will fail to connect with "Protocol not available"

Comment: Note that on Ubuntu 21.10 I had to apt install pipewire-pulse to get this going.

Answer (score 14):

Arch User Here. But love PipeWire. Under all debian/Ubuntu `{18..21}.{04,10}` Version of PW is too old. That's why I am maintaining a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Epipewire-debian/+archive/ubuntu/pipewire-upstream) which will provide latest build of PipeWire(15-16 days of release cycle). You can track latest change on [github](https://github.com/pipewire-debian/pipewire-debian/)  for this PPA.

<strike>On arch linux this process is obtained by {pre,post}_{install,upgrade,remove} function under package's *.install file.</strike>

And under Ubuntu/Debian It will be achieved by some simple `{pre,post}{inst,rm}` scripts. I will be updated these in next release definitely. This Already had been done.

**EDIT 1 -**
**For a detailed Installation instructions Please follow  [github wiki](https://github.com/pipewire-debian/pipewire-debian/wiki).**

With PipeWire I am also packaging **`blueman-git`** (git version of blueman). It has some serious needed feature to work with PipeWire. Don't worry it also will not break anything but increase your productivity upto a level higher.

**EDIT 2 -**
**The Launchpad PPA will work under All `debian/ubuntu` based distros.** Don't worry! install it, test it and file bugs to upstream to help it's developers to make PipeWire even more better.

**EDIT 3 -**
**Now `PipeWire 0.3.27` and on wards will support under `debian/ubuntu 18.04` also.**

Comment: Thank you, nice work. For some reason I dont have the example file systemd/user/pipewire-pulse.* after installing this, any idea?

Comment: OK dont worry, I got it working after following the instructions on your github rather than whats posted above here.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Follow GitHub instructions and voila.

Comment: This is a positive development! Does this work with Linux Mint 20.1?

Comment: @mcarans Yes, It will work on all debian/ubuntu based distros. Linux Mint 20.1 also work with the PPA.

Comment: Too old for what? Is it buggy, or missing features, or outright doesn't work? (What does one get in exchange for adding a third party PPA instead of using the Ubuntu-sanctioned package?)

Comment: I didn't understand the blueman-git installation step (I am quite newbie in linux). Should I install the PipeWire OR the blueman-git? I have blueman here, the apt install one.

Comment: this is a life saver contribution! thanks, just follow the instruction till the end

Answer (score 8):

**On Ubuntu 21.10**

First install the missing PipeWire packages:

`sudo apt install pipewire-pulse pipewire-audio-client-libraries`

If you want bluetooth audio to work you also need to install:

`sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth`

After that feel free to disable pulseaudio and enable PipeWire running theses commands (without root):

```
// Disable and stop the PulseAudio service with:
systemctl --user --now disable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
// Enable and start the new pipewire-pulse service with:
systemctl --user --now enable pipewire pipewire-pulse
```

And that's it! You can confirm everything worked by running:

`pactl info | grep '^Server Name'`

The output should be similar to this:

`Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.32)`

Restart Pipewire services

`systemctl --user restart pipewire pipewire-pulse`

Comment: Great, thanks for that!

Comment: Necessary comment for 21.10 users, the accepted comment doesn't work on 21.10.

Answer (score -2):

You need to edit: `/etc/pipewire/media-session.d/media-session.conf`

And un-comment at least `alsa-monitor` under `session.modules`.