# Why is my sound extremely distorted in Ubuntu Studio 21.10?

Tags: sound, kubuntu, ubuntu-studio, 21.10, jack

Audio is **extremely** distorted in Ubuntu Studio 21.10 using JACK on my Lenovo Thinkpad P15v Gen 2, using the built-in Intel Tiger Lake audio hardware.

It appears that all sound on the system is affected; LMMS, Hydrogen, Spotify, and even system sound effects (e.g. the 'blip' sound when adjusting volume) are all hyper-amplified into squelchy static.

Some apps, such as Spotify, become less distorted as I reduce the main volume, but I need to reduce the level to 15% or lower for the distortion to become inaudible.

Other apps, such as LMMS, retain their shrieking squelch no matter how far I pull back sliders in QASMixer.

The problem seems to be caused by some part of Ubuntu Studio's JACK configuration. I experience the same problem on a fresh install of Ubuntu Studio 21.10, and also on a vanilla install of Kubuntu where I have used the Ubuntu Studio installer. The Kubuntu installation did not have this problem before I ran the Ubuntu Studio installer.

I have tried changing JACK sample rate, buffer size, and periods with no noticeable change in the audio quality.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this, I solved my audio problems by switching to pipewire and disabling pulseaudio.

More info here:

[How to replace pulseaudio with pipewire on Ubuntu 21.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333404/how-to-replace-pulseaudio-with-pipewire-on-ubuntu-21-04)

https://github.com/pipewire-debian/pipewire-debian/wiki

https://wiki.debian.org/PipeWire

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `--sync` or `-S` option on `jackd`? It somehow resolved the distortion on my Thinkpad E14 Gen2 when using JACK.