# Cant make bluetooth A2DP work on my earbuds

Tags: sound, bluetooth

- Ubuntu20.04
- Jabra Elite 7 active

Used to work on Ubuntu18.04 and the earbuds would connect with A2DP (high fidelity). Now I cannot - just HSP/HFP.

What happens is that it "connects" but there is no sound. Switching back to HSP/HFP works.

I tried a lot of different approaches:

1. editing /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.target.wants/bluetooth.service
2. editing /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
3. editing /etc/pulse/system.pa
4. reinstalling: pulseaudio-module-bluetooth bluetooth "bluez-*" bluez
5. playing with service bluetooth
6. bluetoothctl

Nothing worked...

I don't get even how to debug / research this further. What can I do?

Comment: Ubuntu next release will switch to pipewire. It has better support for BT https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333404/how-to-replace-pulseaudio-with-pipewire-on-ubuntu-21-04 so it might be a workaround for your problems,

Comment: Looked it up. Didn't help me, but it led me to this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1339897/768410 which did help, so thanks!!

Comment: cool :) piperwire in 22.10 will support both :)

Comment: Yep, this is what I linked